# Using dBase table converted from CSV to Make Route Event Layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, table, linear-referencing, dbf

I'm using the tool 'Make Route Event Layer' and I need to use a dBase table for the event table, but the data are saved in a CSV file. When I try with dBase table that I created myself all go good, but when I use a dBase table converted from the .csv file (using the converter of ArcGIS) ArcGIS crashes.

It is due to the fact that the tool convert also all the line without value and then I have a dBase table with many null line?

Is there a method to avoid that?

How can I convert only the line with a value?

I also tried to do it directly with the .csv file and with an Excel file and it always crashes

Comment: After some more tries I really think that the problem is the length of the table. In fact 1 million lines is too much. Even if only some line contain value, when I convert Excel ( or I use directly it) it create lines for all the Excel sheet till the end, even if it do not contain eny values.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't convert from a dbase to csv or that you can't create a dynamic layer from csv?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the size of the resulting dBase file.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by copying the data and pasting them directly into the dBase table. Now I have just the data that I want without null lines